# Evento Click não funciona em controle personalizado

Tags: c#, winforms, eventos, usercontrol

Eu criei um botão (UserControl), até aí ok, mas quando eu boto um evento `Click` nele, não funciona, já tentei com o evento MouseDown, também não funcionou.
Não acho que seja isto, mas este botão tem uma `Label` que preenche todo ele, soque a label é um componente do controle.
Um print:
[image]

Comment: @vnbrs Que seria o handler?

Comment: @vnbrs Não... achei que apenas adicionar o evento no controle já funcionaria

Comment: @vnbrs Eu não tratei o evento posterioramente...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O evento de clique não é disparado quando você clica nos elementos filhos. O `UserControl.Click` só é disparado ao clicar no `UserControl` e não na `Label` que o contrapõe.

No seu `UserControl` trate os cliques dos elementos filhos para que o `UserControl.Click` seja disparado.

```
componente1.Click += new EventHandler(filho_Click);
componente2.Click += new EventHandler(filho_Click);
componente3.Click += new EventHandler(filho_Click);
```

e o handler do evento:

```
private void filho_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    this.OnClick(e);
}
```